# Custom cell class in data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I created a matrix control which derives from `DataGrid` which should be able to display complex types in the cells. These complex types should be then styled by a template.

When using `AutoGenerateColumns` the `DataGrid`will automatically create the columns and cell types based on the list type assigned to `ItemsSource`.

I want to replace the row, column and cell type of the grid to perform custom operations and bindings with the view model bound to it. I already was able to create a custom row and column. Is there any way to derive from `DataGridCell` and make the data grid use that type instead of the default type?

I had a look at the .net source code and I saw that the row uses the `DataGridCellsPresenter` to create the cells, but that property is not accessible.

```
public class MatrixControl : DataGrid
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty COLUMN_HEADER_TEMPLATE_PROPERTY = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ColumnHeaderTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(MatrixControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

  public DataTemplate ColumnHeaderTemplate { get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(COLUMN_HEADER_TEMPLATE_PROPERTY); } set { SetValue(COLUMN_HEADER_TEMPLATE_PROPERTY, value); } }

  private MatrixViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as MatrixViewModel; } }

  public MatrixControl()
  {
    DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
    SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.CellOrRowHeader;
    AutoGenerateColumns = true;
  }

  private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    ItemsSource = ViewModel.Rows.Select(c => new Row(c, ViewModel));
  }

  protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
    Columns.Clear();
    foreach (var column in ViewModel.Columns)
    {
      Columns.Add(new MatrixColumn(column)
      {
        HeaderTemplate = ColumnHeaderTemplate
      });
    }
  }
}

class MatrixColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
  public object Value { get; }

  public MatrixColumn(object value)
  {
    Value = value;
  }
}

class Row
{
  public object Value { get; }

  public Row(object value)
  {
    Value = value;
  }
}

class MatrixViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<object> Columns { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<object> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Update: Attempt to replace the `DataGridCellsPresenter`

```
// in data grid class
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
  return new MatrixRow();
}

class MatrixRow : DataGridRow
{       
  public MatrixRow()
  {
    var cellPresenterProperty = GetType().GetProperty("CellsPresenter", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
    cellPresenterProperty.SetValue(this, new MatrixCellPresenter());
  }
}

class MatrixCellPresenter : DataGridCellsPresenter
{
  protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
  {
    // won't get called, the presenter is overriden by the internal one
    return new MatrixCell();
  }
}
```

Comment: The default template of the `DataGridRow` uses a `DataGridDetailsPresenter` to create the cells. You can override the `GetContainerForItemOverride()` method of the `DataGrid` to return custom row containers and then implement your own custom `DataGridDetailsPresenter`. This will require quite some effort though.

Comment: I tried that already deriving from `DataGridRow` but then again, I can not override the `DataGridDetailsPresenter`, it is hidden in the internal field. It seems that the internal `DataGridDetailsPresenter` instance will apply itself to all rows automatically, so it does not make sense to set it on the row by reflection

Comment: You may still create a custom `DataGridDetailsPresenter`. Or a custom `DataGridRow`.

Comment: Ofcourse I can create one, but how would I tell the data grid to use it?

Comment: I updated the question. When looking at the `DataGrid` source code, I can n ot figure out how and where the `DataGridCellsPresenter` gets instanciated...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812374/how-can-i-override-datagrid-selection-behavior).

The code from the question is good so far, the only thing which was neccessary to do is to overwrite the `MatrixRow` template in xaml. For the sake of completeness I post the xaml code from the other question:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MatrixRow}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MatrixRow}">
        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Make sure to register your custom DataGridCellsPresenter here as following -->

            <local:MatrixCellPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                              ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"
                                SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation=
                                  "{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, 
                                  ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical},
                                  Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
                             SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                             Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
                              ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, 
                              Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
          </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```