# Select another DataGrid row only if condition is satisfied - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid in WPF.

I have a situation in which if one row is selected and then user selects another row then there should be a message like -

> Are you sure you want to select this?

And if user says yes then only the another row should get selected.

But, In current case, The `SelectionChanged` Event is already called and new row gets selected.

What I tried is to use some Property Binding

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
     <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsToEnableRowSelection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>                        
</Style>
```

In the back end -

```
private void MyDataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want save changes?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
    {
        e.Handled = false;
        IsToEnableRowSelection = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        IsToEnableRowSelection = false;
    }
}
```

Property Declaration with INotify Event -

```
public bool IsToEnableRowSelection
{
    get
    {
        return enableSelectedRow;
    }
    set
    {
        enableSelectedRow = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsToEnableRowSelection");
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName()] string name = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

But I am unable to get desired behaviour.

> So, To sum it up, I want I want the new row to be selected only if the
>   user confirm it to get selected in Message Box. Else the old selected
>   row should only remain selected.

Comment: You can find solution here: [How can I override DataGrid selection behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43867250/7713750)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I override DataGrid selection behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812374/how-can-i-override-datagrid-selection-behavior)

Comment: @Rekshino - Let me check. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this i hope this will help you.

```
 Object _SelectedItem; //_SelectedItem is used to avoid the repeated loops
    DataGridCell _FocusedCell; //_FocusedCell is used to restore focus
    private void MyDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (_SelectedItem == MyDataGrid.SelectedItem)
        {
            return;
        }
        _SelectedItem = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem;


        if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.RemovedItems[0] != null && MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want save changes?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {

            _SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
              new Action(() =>
              {
                  MyDataGrid.SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
                  if (_FocusedCell != null)
                  {
                      _FocusedCell.Focus();
                  }
              }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send); //hope a high priority can avoid flicking.
        }
    }

    private void DataGridCell_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _FocusedCell = sender as DataGridCell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `DataGridRow` something like this:

```
private void DataGridRow_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (dg.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        HitTestResult hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(dg, e.GetPosition(dg));
        DataGridCell cell = FindParent<DataGridCell>(hitTestResult.VisualHit);

        if (MessageBox.Show(this, "confirm....?", "caption..:", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            dg.SelectedItem = cell.DataContext;
            cell.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridRow_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
</Style>
```

Comment: @ArpitGupta: Did you try this?